# Ayuda en el lenguaje C

Tags: c

Este es el código que tengo hasta el momento lo que esta funcionando por ahora es la selección de quien juega primero, después me pide la selección de cada casilla con las coordenadas correspondientes y para hacer ese paso me confunde un poco

Adjunto codigo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void Intro_Primera (char c[4][4]);
void tablero (char c[4][4]);
void sorteo (int a, char c[4][4]);
void partida (char c[4][4],int juego);

int main ()
{
    int a;
    char c [4][4];
    char d [3][3];
    printf ("......Bienvenido al Juego TA-TE-TI......\n\n");
    Intro_Primera (c);
    tablero (c);
    sorteo (a,c);

}

void Intro_Primera (char c [4][4])
{
    int i,j;
    char a={'.'};
    for (i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<4;j++)
        {


            if (i==0)
            {
                if (j==0)
                    c[i][j]=(' ');
                else if (j==1)
                    c[i][j]=('A');
                else if (j==2)
                    c[i][j]=('B');
                else if (j==3)
                    c[i][j]=('C');

            }
            else
            c[i][j]= a;

            if (i==1 & j==0)
                c[i][j]=('1');
            else if (i==2 & j==0)
                c[i][j]=('2');
            else if (i==3 & j==0)
                c[i][j]=('3');
        }

    }
}

void tablero (char c[4][4])
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<4; j++)
        {
            if (j<3)
            {
                printf (" %c |",c[i][j]);
            }
            else
            {
                printf (" %c ",c[i][j]);
            }
        }
        if (i<3)
        {
            printf ("\n--------------\n");
        }
    }
    printf ("\n\n");
}

void sorteo (int a,char c[4][4])
{
    int juego=0;
    srand (time(NULL));
    int n=rand()% 2;
    if (n==0)
    {
        printf ("Usted comienza el Juego\n\nUsted empieza jugando con la X\n");
        juego=0;
        partida(c,juego);

    }
    else
    {
        printf ("La Computadora comienza el Juego\n\nUsted empieza jugando con la O\n");
        juego=1;
    }
}

void partida (char c[4][4],int juego)
{
    char a;
    int i,j;
    if (juego==0)
    {
        for (i=0; i<9;i++)
        {
            printf ("Ingrese las Coordenadas\n");
            scanf("%c",&a);
            if(a=='1A')
                    c[1][1]='X';
            else if (a=='2A')
                    c[2][1]='X';
            else if (a=='3A')
                    c[3][1]='X';
            else if (a=='1B')
                    c[1][2]='X';
            else if (a=='2B')
                    c[2][2]='X';
            else if (a=='3B')
                    c[3][2]='X';
            else if (a=='1C')
                    c[1][3]='X';
            else if (a=='2C')
                    c[2][3]='X';
            else if (a=='3C')
                    c[3][3]='X';
            tablero (c);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesante, la idea de hacer un TATETI, así es como lo resolví yo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

//
// struct tateti
//
// matrix    = Matriz de caracteres
// letras[0] = Letra que usa la persona
// letras[1] = Letra que usa la computadora
// jugador   = Jugador actual, 0=Persona, 1=Computadora
// ganador   = Jugador que ganó, -1 = Ninguno, 0 = Persona, 1 = Computadora
//

struct tateti
{
    int matrix[3][3];
    int letras[2];
    int jugador;
    int ganador;
};
void print_tateti(struct tateti* t)
{
    int i,j;
    system("cls");
    printf("   | A | B | C |\n");
    printf("---+---+---+---|\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d |", i+1);
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if(j < 3)
            {
                printf(" %c |", t->matrix[i][j]);
            }
            else
            {
                printf (" %c ", t->matrix[i][j]);
            }
        }
        if(i < 2)
            printf("\n---+---+---+---|\n");
        else
            printf("\n---------------|\n");
    }
}
int check_tateti(struct tateti* t, int c)
{
    int i;

    // Comprobar filas
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if(t->matrix[i][0] == c && t->matrix[i][1] == c && t->matrix[i][2] == c)
            return 1;
    }
    // Comprobar columnas
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if(t->matrix[0][i] == c && t->matrix[1][i] == c && t->matrix[2][i] == c)
            return 1;
    }
    // Comprobar diagonales
    if(t->matrix[0][0] == c && t->matrix[1][1] == c && t->matrix[2][2] == c)
        return 1;
    if(t->matrix[2][0] == c && t->matrix[1][1] == c && t->matrix[0][2] == c)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
int jugar_tateti(struct tateti* t)
{
    int c;
    int ok;
    int col = -1;
    int row = -1;

    // Jugar
    if(t->jugador == 0)
    {
        ok = 0;
        do
        {
            col = -1;
            row = -1;
            printf("Ingrese las coordenadas:");
            while(col == -1)
            {
                printf("\nFila: ");
                c = getch();
                printf("%c", c);
                if(c >= '1' && c <= '3')
                {
                    col = (c-'1');
                }
            }
            while(row == -1)
            {
                printf("\nColumna: ");
                c = toupper(getch());
                printf("%c", c);
                if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'C')
                {
                    row = (c-'A');
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
            if(t->matrix[col][row] == ' ')
            {
                ok = 1;
                t->matrix[col][row] = t->letras[0];
                getch();
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Celda ocupada, intentelo otra vez\n");
                getch();
                print_tateti(t);
            }
        }
        while(!ok);
    }
    else
    {
        ok = 0;
        do
        {
            row = rand()%3;
            col = rand()%3;
            if(t->matrix[col][row] == ' ')
            {
                ok = 1;
                t->matrix[col][row] = t->letras[1];
            }
        }
        while(!ok);
    }
    //
    // Comprobar si ganó el usuario
    //
    if(check_tateti(t, t->letras[0]))
    {
        t->ganador = 0;
        return 0;
    }
    //
    // Comprobar si ganó la computadora
    //
    if(check_tateti(t, t->letras[1]))
    {
        t->ganador = 1;
        return 0;
    }
    //
    // Comprobar si se llegó al final y no hay ganadores
    //
    ok = 1;
    for(col = 0; col < 3 && ok; col++)
    {
        for(row = 0; row < 3 && ok; row++)
        {
            if(t->matrix[col][row] == ' ')
            {
                ok = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    if(ok)
    {
        t->ganador = -1;
        return 0;
    }
    // Cambiar de jugador
    t->jugador = !t->jugador;
    return 1;
}
void iniciar_tateti(struct tateti* t)
{
    int n;
    int i,j;

    srand(time(NULL));
    //
    // Iniciar matrix
    //
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            t->matrix[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
    //
    // Seleccionar jugador inicial, computadora o persona, y caracter por jugador
    //
    n = rand()%2;
    t->letras[n] = 'X';
    t->letras[!n] = 'O';
    t->jugador = rand()%2;
    printf("Usted juega con la \'%c\'\n", t->letras[0]);
    printf("La computadora juega con la \'%c\'\n", t->letras[1]);
    if(t->jugador == 0)
    {
        printf("\nUsted comienza el juego. ");
    }
    else// if(t->jugador == 1)
    {
        printf("\nLa Computadora comienza el juego. ");
        jugar_tateti(t);
    }
    printf("Presione una tecla para continuar ...");
    getch();
    print_tateti(t);
}

void main()
{
    int c;
    struct tateti t;

    printf("......Bienvenido al Juego TA-TE-TI......\n\n");
    getch();
    do
    {
        system("cls");
        iniciar_tateti(&t);
        while(jugar_tateti(&t))
        {
            print_tateti(&t);
        }
        print_tateti(&t);
        switch(t.ganador)
        {
            case 0:
                printf("\nGanastes\n");
                break;
            case 1:
                printf("\nGano la computadora\n");
                break;
            case -1:
                printf("\nNo hay ganadores\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("\nError\n");
                break;
        }
        getch();
        system("cls");
        printf("Quieres jugar otra vez?\nS = Si\nN = No\n");
        do
        {
            c = toupper(getch());
            if(c == 'S')
                break;
            else if(c == 'N')
                return;
        }
        while(1);
    }
    while(1);
}
```